# Print Spooler uses 50% CPU power and hangs, cannot print, Server 2012

Tags: printing, windows-server-2012, network-printer, print-spooler

We are having the same reoccurring problem at our company with the print spooler on Windows Server 2012, namely that it's consuming a constant 50% CPU power and we cannot print, accessing the list of printers causes explorer to hang. 
Things we googled and tried already:

- Restarting the spooler
- Deleting the contents of C:\WINDOWS\system32\spool\printers
- Deleting old jobs from C:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS[servername]
- Removing printers from the account
- Removing printer drivers
- Restarting the server
- Installing latest OS updates

The system is a Windows Server 2012 (non R2). 
The printers were installed from the account that is using the printers programatically from the web application.
The drivers are fetched from our main printer servers that host all printers (and they seem to work fine)

We thought of bad drivers causing this problem but as I wrote we already uninstalled them (althought files remain in C:\Windows\System32\spool\drivers).

What are we missing here?

Comment: Try to delete all files and folders in C:\WINDOWS\System32\spool\PRINTERS

Comment: @whs That was literally the second bullet point they mentioned. Did you even read the full question?

Comment: Yeah right sorry. I must have been sidetracked.